# combine value from array with input element to create a reactjs

Tags: reactjs, reactjs.net

I have a use case where i need to replace '_____' with input tags.  I am using Reactjs.NET.  I thought I could do the below, but I get an error.

The output is:

> Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getDOMNode' of undefined  and Uncaught Error: Minified exception occurred; use the non-minified dev environment for the full error message and additional helpful warnings.

```
handleEntry:function(){
   var x = this.refs.value1.getDOMNode().value;
   console.log(x);
},
render: function () {
   var DisplayName = "abcd_____ efg _____ ijkl";
   var splitTheString = DisplayName.split('_____');
   var numOfDashes = (DisplayName.match(/_____/g) || []).length;
   if (numOfDashes === 2) {
    return <div>{splitTheString[0]} <input ref="value1" type="text" onBlur={this.handleEntry}/> {splitTheString[1]} <input ref="value2" type="text" onBlur={this.handleEntry}/> {splitTheString[2]}</div>;
    } else {
        return <div>{splitTheString[0]} <input ref="value1" type="text" onBlur={this.handleEntry}/></div>;
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't use `getDOMNode` to get the value, you just say `this.refs.value1.value` https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html#the-ref-string-attribute

Comment: i used this.refs.value1.value now but i still get error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined when i tab out of the first input and the 2nd one does not even trigger the handleEntry